# Reflux callback after store is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, refluxjs

I'm working on Chrome Extension using React.js and Reflux. Now I need to notify all parts of extension about changes when store is updated with one callback.

Something like:

```
function(newStore){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateStore', store: newStore});
}
```

Where is the point in Reflux for adding such callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't built a chrome extension using Reflux but in general the pattern is to call:

```
store.listen(function(data) {
    // data is whatever your store invoked by saying this.trigger(...)
});
```

The callback function will be invoked whenever your store calls trigger with new data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do. Would you be able to provide some more code to show the different pieces of the whole?